# git: creating a branch which cannot be merged into another one

Tags: git, merge, hook

I want to create a branch that is only for experimentals.
It never should be merged into another branch or master.
Is it possible to prevent this it somehow?

Comment: What context?  What does your org do?  Without this info, it's hard to say.  Otherwise, create branch in your local repo and never push it nor request a pull.  If you mean more than that, please edit your question, adding more information.

Comment: But why not let it be merged into another experiment? In general, this is enforced at the pull request level. If somebody submits a pull request into master, and it contains a merge from a "don't merge from this" branch, then reject the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, this is possible, but perhaps the Github-way is a suitable solution for your problem:
In Github it is easily possible for every user to fork existing repositories. If they want to contribute to a project, they work on their own copy of the repository. When they are done, they make a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) in the original repository. This pull request can only be merged by the owner of the original repository.

tl;dr: Perhaps cloning/forking the whole repository instead of creating a branch is the way to go.